I have issues while setting up video creation in Playwright
This is my playwright.config.ts configuration:
use: {
    /* Base URL to use in actions like `await page.goto('/')`. */
    baseURL: 'myurl',

    /* Collect trace when retrying the failed test. See https://playwright.dev/docs/trace-viewer */
    trace: 'on',
    video: {
      mode: 'retain-on-failure',
      size: {width:640, height:480} 
    },
    screenshot: 'only-on-failure'
  },

I added this in my test:
let browser: { close: () => Promise<void> };

    test.beforeEach(async({ page }) => {
        const browser = await chromium.launch({
            slowMo: 500,
            headless: false
        })
    
        const context = await browser.newContext({
            recordVideo: {
                dir: 'videos/',
                size: {width: 800, height: 600}
            }
        });
    
        /*await context.tracing.start({
            screenshots: true,
            snapshots: true,
        });*/
    
        //page = await context.newPage();
    
        //await context.close();
    
        // my beforeEach actions
    
        await browser.close();
    
    })
    
    test.afterAll(async () => {
        await browser?.close();
    });

    test.describe('General description of the tests', () => {
        test('First test description', async ({ page }) => {
            //actions
        }
    }

I am getting the error: Must start traces before stopping. I also had the error: end of central directory record signature not found, but it doesn't appear after I wrapped up my test into describe block and added the code above.

Please post the full stack trace(s).
